# eclipse installation error on laptop

Tags: eclipse

I am installing Eclipse to my laptop (Win 7 Professional 64 bits, with JDK (64 bit) pre-installed). I see an error. Below is part of the log file. Help is greatly appreciated.

> [2015-09-15 10:25:35] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an issue in the artifacts.xml file located in the root directory of Eclipse. Try copying your artifact file somewhere else and then restart eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error occurs during the installation process. Since the installation stops before completion, I cannot find the artifacts.xml file in the root dir of Eclipse. As a matter of fact, the only file I see is the setup.log fie. Any other suggestion?